# How to validate deleting a DNS entry with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, active-directory

I have a (at least what I think) tricky problem with a Server 2008 R2 domain. I wrote a cleanup script for AD computer accounts. Beside the account in AD I want to delete SCCM and DNS accounts. But with DNS I have a problem. I need to log everything as my script will run timed as a job each day. 
With the normal AD module cmdlets all work great by using something like this:

```
Remove-ADComputer -Identity $account -confirm:$false

if($?){
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: successfully deleted account `"$($account.name)`" with LastLogondate `"$($account.LastLogondate)`", full path `"$($account.distinguishedname)`"" -LogPath $logFile
} else {
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: failed to delete account `"$($account.name)`": $($error[0].Exception.Message)" -LogPath $logFile -Level 'Warn'
}
```

For deleting old DNS entries I found two solutions for Server 2008 R2 (I can't use those cool new Server 2012 DNS modules for ps):

```
dnscmd $DNSServer /RecordDelete $ZoneName $Computer A /f
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dnsserver -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AType  -Filter "domainname = '$computer'" | Remove-WmiObject
```

But both commands (dnscmd and Remove-WmiObject) always return true, even if there were no records in DNS matching my computer account's name. So I cant use a similar construct as above.

So I tried something like this:

```
try{
    [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($computer)
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dns -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AType  -Filter "domainname = '$computer'" | Remove-WmiObject -whatif
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dns -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AAAAType  -Filter "domainname = '$computer'" | Remove-WmiObject -whatif
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: successfully deleted DNS entry for `"$($computer)`"" -LogPath $logFile
}
catch {
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: failed to delete DNS entry for `"$($computer)`": $($error[0].Exception.Message)" -LogPath $logFile -Level 'Warn'
}
```

With the static function `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($computer)` I test if there is at least an ipv4 entry (as ipv6 is deactivated on my system I would get an exception if there is only an ipv6 entry. If both ipv4 and ipv6 exist it works). If there is an entry it proceeds with the Remove-WmiObject cmdlet for ipv4 and ipv6. 
If there is no such entry in DNS I get an exception and directly jump into the catch-block where I log the error.
But even with this method I have no clue later if the Remove-WmiObject was successful. I would have to do a `ipconfig /flushdns` and re-run the command `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($computer)` to see if it now fails and interpret this as "entries deleted".

Please, is there another cmdlet or way for Server 2008 R2 to delete an entry from DNS and validate if the deletion was successful? Help ;)

Comment: I wrote this a very long time ago: https://dnsshell.codeplex.com/. It can do what you ask and it was tested against 2008.

Comment: Hi. I already found that one ;) but I would have to load other scripts on our infrasteucture. But I keep it in mind.

Comment: Understandable :) WMI works, it's all dnsshell does, you just have to muck around with the syntax rather a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use those cool new Server 2012 DNS modules for ps

Yes you can, as long as you have at least one machine new enough to run them. They work just fine against a 2008 R2 domain controller. This would simplify things a lot!

Otherwise, you can still use CIM/WMI calls to retrieve the value of the record like you're already doing instead of using `GetHostEntry`.

#### Example, courtesy of [Jon  Dechiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6595659/jon-dechiro)

```
if (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dnsserver -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AType -Filter "domainname = '$computer'") { 
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: failed to delete DNS entry for "$($computer)": Entry still exists on $dnsserver" -LogPath $logFile -Level 'Warn' 
} else { 
    Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: successfully deleted DNS entry for "$($computer)"" -LogPath $logFile 
}
```

Comment: Hm have to check if we have 2012 on our task servers running the scripts. The the Remove-WmiObject cmdlet I already tried my luck, but as I said they return always true :(

Comment: @user1276012 I'm saying after you run `Remove-WmiObject`, use `Get-WmiObject` again as an alternative to trying to flush the DNS cache and resolve with `GetHostEntry`. Still not great; definitely try for the newer cmdlets. You may also be able to use the cmdlets on a downlevel OS by upgrading Windows Management Framework, but some cmdlets do actually require a newer OS version, so you'll have to check on that. I don't know why these would since they are actually thin wrappers around the WMI calls anyway as far as I can tell.

Comment: As briantist suggested, I would do it like this:  `if (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dnsserver -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AType  -Filter "domainname = '$computer'") {
   Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: failed to delete DNS entry for `"$($computer)`": Entry still exists on $dnsserver" -LogPath $logFile -Level 'Warn'
}
else{
 Write-Log -LogContent "Delete-OldADaccount: successfully deleted DNS entry for `"$($computer)`"" -LogPath $logFile
}`

Comment: @briantist Didn't want to steal your thunder. Feel free to add to your answer. and I'll delete the comment because the syntax looks like a mess in the comment anyway.

Comment: The new commands are backed by new WMI classes. The old WMI classes for DNS are inconsistently implemented and are pretty horrible to work with. A significant portion of the management wrapper I created in DnsShell is concerned with attempting to prevent things getting as far as WMI.

Comment: @JonDechiro I added it to mine, but there's room for more than 1 answer. Feel free to post it as your own, and I'll remove that content from mine.

Comment: Good workaround and saves me the use of the static function :) thanks to both of you.

Comment: But the cmd `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $dnsserver -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -class MicrosoftDNS_AType -Filter "domainname = '$computer'"` will not flush the local DNS cache right? I should also perform a `ipconfig /flushdns` before running into the if-clause, shouldnt I? Or is the cmd bypassing the local DNS cache?

Comment: @user1276012 it does not flush the cache, but the beauty of it is that you don't need to. You're reading the value directly from the DNS server, not doing a DNS lookup, so none of the caches matter.